# Why Sub query in leftjoin in typeorm giving me error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, nestjs, typeorm

If i am defining innerjoin or leftjoin in subquery of leftjoinandselect, then it is giving me error sqlMessage: "Duplicate column name 'id'".

For example

```
.leftJoinAndSelect(
            (qb) =>
              qb
                .from(Email, 'email')
                .innerJoin(User, 'user')
                .where('user.account = :account', {
                  accountId: 4,
                }),
            'email',
            '`email`.`id` = 1',
          )
```

The above will give me error "Duplicate column name 'id'"

But if i remove innerJoin then it is working fine and giving expected result.

```
.leftJoinAndSelect(
                (qb) =>
                  qb
                    .from(Email, 'email'),
                'email',
                '`email`.`id` = 1',
              )
```

Any idea why is it giving me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that both `email` and `user` tables have `id` columns.
Can you try the following code?:

```js
.leftJoinAndSelect(
            (qb) =>
              qb    
                .select("user.id", "user_id")
                .addSelect("email.id", "email_id")
                // Add whatever you want by .addSelect method
                .from(Email, 'email')
                .innerJoin(User, 'user')
                .where('user.account = :account', {
                  accountId: 4,
                }),
            'email',
            '`email`.`id` = 1',
          )
```

Comment: This is working, but now there is one more issue, we are not getting the seubquery selected data with getMany, instead we have to use getRawMany & map it manually . It would be great if we can use getMany with subqueries.